# Unable to figure out whether to use "," or "+" in console.log in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the config.json file:

```
{
"username": "myname",
"api-key": "test",
"name": "testname",
"version": 1
}
```

This is the node.js file

```
var fs=require("fs");
console.log("Start");
var contents=fs.readFileSync("config.json");
console.log("Contents: " +contents);
var config=JSON.parse(contents);
console.log("Username: ", config.username);
```

Now whether I use

```
console.log("Username: ", config.username);
```

or I use

```
console.log("Username:" +config.username);
```

I get the same result in the output. However it gives different results while logging other variables. Unable to get when "," is used and when "+" is used. Any pointers?

Comment: Could you describe the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `+` then that is a [concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators), and you pass a single string (or number) to `log()`.

If you use a `,`, then you are passing multiple arguments.

If you pass multiple arguments, and you aren't using a formatting string, then they will each get logged via `inspect`.

See the documentation for [console.log](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data) and [util.inspect](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the + operator varies from a concatenation operator if one or more of the variables is a string, versus an addition operator if both variables are non-stringified numbers. The , separator always converts each variable to a string separately and logs them separately.